# Decrypt DTLS traffic when using the Cisco AnyConnect Client

Tags: vpn, decryption, cisco

I am using the Cisco AnyConnect Client 4.7 to connect to a VPN. I need to decrypt the traffic to examine the packets and understand how VPN works. I have read about providing the PSK to Wireshark, but I can't find somewhere explaining how to get that when using this Cisco Client.

Additionally, I need to do the same using the discontinued Cisco VPN client which supports IPsec. Again, I don't know how to obtain the session keys to decrypt ESP traffic.

Just to make clear, I am not trying to perform an mitm attack, I have credentials and am connected to the VPN as a legitimate user.